# asp.net MVC3 microsoft web Helpers error. can't access it on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web, helper

i installed the microsoft web Helpers from NuGet and it went well done. i can't access it from my views, only on my controls. there are no errors atached. i just cant see it there. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers
```

to your view. Or if you don't want to add this namespace to all views, simply add it to the `~/views/web.config` `<namespaces>` section:

```
<add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
```

Comment: i tried that too, but ther is no "web" inside Microsoft although i have it on my references. i put it on my ~/views/web.config too. ;/

Comment: If you installed the `microsoft-web-helpers` NuGet there should be such namespace. Don't trust Visual Studio Intellisense. It might underline it with a red squiggle but this doesn't mean that your application won't work. Try running it. Sometimes you might need to reopen the Razor page or restart VS for changes to take effect.

Comment: God bless you Darin. Intellisense really betrayed me ;). i was getting nuts already. it's all working fine now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the namespace of your helper method in root web.config. It will fix the issue for all views. some thing like :

```
<add namespace="namespace of Your Helper Class" />
```